# Updating ObservableCollection using delegates in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, delegates, observablecollection

I have three ViewModels: MainViewModel, PreferencesViewModel and ColourControllerViewModel - the latter 2 are properties of the MainViewModel.

ColourControllerViewModel is used for the 'ColourSelector' view, where various colours can be created and deleted. It contains an ObservableCollection of ColourViewModel, which has a property detailing the colour, and a bool property determining if it should be shown on the preferences tab (DisplayOnPreferences).

PreferencesViewModel is used for the 'Preferences' view, which contains a combo box of colours - this is represent by an ObservableCollection of ColourViewModel, and only those ColourViewModels where DisplayOnPreferences == true should be displayed.

My question is, what's the easiest way to do this? Currently, I am using an Action delegate called UpdateList() which passes the updated list from ColourControllerViewModel to MainViewModel, which in turn updates the PreferencesViewModel. I don't really like this though, it feels like there's a better way.

Should there be a single ObservableCollection of ColourViewModel on MainViewModel that is updated/accessed by either instance?

Here are the classes:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
      private ColourMappingControllerViewModel _colourMappingControllerViewModel;
      private PreferencesControllerViewModel _preferencesTabViewModel;


      public MainViewModel()
      {
        // Initialise the database Handler
        dbHandler = DatabaseHandler.DbHandlerInstance;

        _colourMappingControllerViewModel = new ColourMappingControllerViewModel(dbHandler.GetColourMappingsList(), UpdateColourList);
        _preferencesTabViewModel = new PreferencesControllerViewModel(dbHandler.GetPreferences, ColourMappingList)    
       }

      public ObservableCollection<ColourMappingViewModel> ColourMappingList
      {
          get { return ColourMappingControllerViewModel.ColourMappingList; }        
      }


      public void UpdateColourList(ObservableCollection<ColourMappingViewModel> colourList)
      {
          PreferencesTabViewModel.UpdateColourList(colourList);
      }       
}

public class ColourMappingControllerViewModel : ViewModel
{

    public ColourMappingControllerViewModel(IEnumerable<ColourMapping> colourMappingsList,  Action<ObservableCollection<ColourMappingViewModel>> updateColourListAction)
    {
        InitialiseCommands();
        ColourMappingList = new ObservableCollection<IColourMappingViewModel>(InitialiseColourMappingsList(colourMappingsList));
    }

    public ICommand AddColourMappingCommand { get; set; }
    private void InitialiseCommands()
    {
        AddColourMappingCommand = new DelegatingCommand(AddColourMapping);
    }
    private void AddColourMapping() // Attached to Command on View
    {
        var newColourMapping = new ColourMappingViewModel(
            new ColourMapping());
        ColourMappingList.Add(newColourMapping);
        ColourMappingsCollectionView.MoveCurrentToLast();
        UpdateColourMappingList();
    }


    private void UpdateColourMappingList()
    {
        UpdateColourListAction.Invoke(ColourMappingList);
    }
}


public PreferencesControllerViewModel : ViewModel
{

    public PreferencesControllerViewModel(object preferenceInfo, ObservableCollection<ColourMappingViewModel> colourMappingsList)
    {
        var pciTrendBlocks = pciBlocks;
        ColourMappingsList = colourMappingsList;            
    }

    public void UpdateColourList(ObservableCollection<ColourMappingViewModel> colourList)
    {
        ColourMappingsList = colourList;
    }    

}
```

I know the ObservableCollection class is being misused - it's probably not necessary on the Preferences as it will only be updated in ColourMappingController.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that you need a single `ObservableCollection` that is shared between views. This effectively becomes your "Model" in MVVM.

You may also want to enforce different access semantics by having a [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can be passed to your preferences VM etc. This ensures that only `ColourControllerViewModel` (Which gets the underlying `ObservableCollection`) can actually alter the collection.

In my apps I tend to have a separate data layer, but yes, for now it would be simplest to just add them to `MainViewModel`.

The alternative would be to have `ColourControllerViewModel` be the thing that owns the collection (and exposes it as a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`), and have you `MainViewModel` just pass the collection into any other VM's that need it.

Comment: My issue with this is that how do I pass the ObservableCollection around? The previous lump of code that I'm attempting to update actually passed the instance of mainViewModel to the Preferences and the ColourController, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: No, don't pass the VMs, just pass the collection. eg your Preferences VM takes a ReadOnlyObservableCollection as a constructor parameter.

Comment: I'll give it a go, cheers - although I'm not 100% on why this would work - presumably create it in MainVM, pass it to Pref & Colour, and any updates by Colour should be reflected in Pref.

Comment: It will work because ObservableCollection fires notifications when its content is changed. Colour will update it, a notification will fire, and Pref view binding will update in response.

Comment: Ah, okay then. It works as far as ObservableCollection is concerned, but the difficult lies in that the list shouldn't show ALL of the ObservableCollection - just the subset where DisplayOnTrend == true. I'm not sure how best to achieve this...

Comment: That's a good point. You could use a CollectionView, but you'd still have to refilter on changes. You could subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of every ColourViewModel, and also the ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged event, but this is getting messy. I'd be tempted to just have a proper model layer/class that simply raises an event when anything is edited